# Include another dependency' object/types automatically for my dependency' user

Tags: c#, dependencies, opentk

I made this function in class library:

```cs
public bool GetKey(Keys key)
{
    unsafe { return GLFW.GetKey((GLFWwindow*)_windowPtr, key); }
}
```

where `_windowPtr` is `IntPtr _windowPtr` and `GLFWwindow` is `OpenTK.Windowing.GraphicsLibraryFramework.Window`.

And when i create new project to test the function, to access Keys, i have to do

```cs
using OpenTK.Windowing.GraphicsLibraryFramework
```

which is obvious, but is there a way to auto include this when user uses my dependency?

Comment: Do you understand the different between referencing an assembly and importing a namespace? If not, [read this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/12/referencing-assemblies-and-importing.html) and then get back to us with a question that makes a bit more sense because this one seems to mix up those two concepts.

Comment: I understand the difference, what im looking for is if its possible to provide the user with Keys enum without having to do `using OpenTK.Windowing.GraphicsLibraryFramework;`

Comment: You say you understand the difference but I'm not sure you do. In both your question and your comment, you refer to importing a namespace. For one thing, that would be useless if the appropriate assembly hadn't already been imported. For another, all it does is mean that you can use members of that namespace unqualified. I suggest that you read the page I linked to because, at the very least, you don't understand the difference as well as you think.